# Node.js readline.question await not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});


const answer = await rl.question('What is your favorite food? ');
console.log(`Oh, so your favorite food is ${answer}`);
```

> this is code i used and the await isn't working
> it says to use high level module

Comment: `rl.question` does not return a promise, so async/await is useless here. Take a look at the documentation, there is a example how to use it with the promisify utility: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/readline.html#rlquestionquery-options-callback

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `await` unless the code is inside an `async function` or is inside a module. What you can do is this:

```js
const readline = require('node:readline/promises');
const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});

async function main(){
    const answer = await rl.question('What is your favorite food? ');
    console.log(`Oh, so your favorite food is ${answer}`);
}

main();
```

Comment: [Top-level await has been available since v14.8.](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/top-level-await-is-available-in-node-js-modules/).